# will processing cube be affected by other cubes?

Tags: ssas, cube

In my ssas project, I created two cubes(A and B). There are 1,000 data in cube A, and 20,000,000 in B.
When I process cube A, it will not be completed to process sometimes.
In my idea, only 1,000 data will never cause SSAS crashed, 
so maybe cube B caused.

Does anyone know the affection between cubes when processing cube?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no connection between different cubes except for possible common dimensions.

Dimensions can be used by several cubes. If Cube A has one or more dimensions in common with Cube B, Cube B might be set as unprocessed when Cube A and its dimenions have been reprocessed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and now I understand there is no affection between cubes which database belonging is different.

Comment: Indeed, if you put your cubes and dimensions in separate databases, there will not be any dependencies.